# RASA Dialog Management: Ho to migrate state-based approach to a story-based approach?

Tags: nlp, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, nlu

[RASA NLU](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/generating-nlu-data/) (intents and entities classification) is clear, simple and well implemented.

But one of the things makes RASA different from many competitors is [RASA dialog machine-learning based dialog management](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/writing-stories) (using **stories** and **rules**).

Myself (and I guess many of people that use non RASA framework)  I used to manage task-oriented (conversational) workflows using the concept of state-machine. BTW I developed a small open source project [NaifJs](https://github.com/solyarisoftware/naifjs), that conceptualize a conversation as a sequence (a graph) of states, where each state is a set of valid intents involved in a conversation context.

https://github.com/solyarisoftware/naifjs/blob/master/doc/img/state-machine-1-new.png

So, what is not clear to me is ho to migrate a state-based (or context-based) approach to a story-based approach. Just to simplify/exemplify, I could immagine that given a " dialog flow" realized by conditional statements, I have to "serialize/duplicate" each "if" in multiple "then"stories.

Do you have already explained this problem in some articles?
Maybe a gift for a new RASA blog article/youtube workshop?

---

Thanks

Giorgio